# This tree implementation is not showing any output

Tags: c++, class, oop, data-structures, tree

I have implemented a tree using classes in C++, but the program is not showing any output when I called display function. Can anyone spot the reason?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIOat.png)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class TreeNode                     //node for tree
{
    public:
        int data;
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;
        
        TreeNode(int val)
        {
            data=val;
            left=NULL;
            right=NULL;
        }
};

class Tree                              //class for tree
{
    public:
        TreeNode *r;
        Tree()
        {
            r=NULL;
        }
        
        void insert(int data)
        {
            TreeNode* new_node=new TreeNode(data);
            TreeNode*trav=r;
            while(trav!=NULL)
            {
                if(data>trav->data)
                {
                    if(trav->right==NULL)
                    {
                        trav->right=new_node;   
                        break;
                    }
                    trav=trav->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(trav->left==NULL)
                    {
                        trav->left=new_node;    
                        break;
                    }
                    trav=trav->left;
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        void display()
        {
            print(r);
        }
        
        void print(TreeNode *node)
        {
            if(node!=NULL)
            {
                print(node->left);
                cout<<node->data<<" ";
                print(node->right);
                
            }
        }
        
    
};

int main()                     //main function
{
    Tree T;
    T.insert(10);
    T.insert(1);
    T.insert(2);
    T.insert(100);
    T.display();

}
```

Comment: The `Tree()` contructor is wrong, when you `r->left = NULL;`, `r` has not yet been initialized, it points nowhere. There are probably other bugs. you need to debug this, using your debugger or adding some output at stategic places so you can see what your code does.

Comment: Is that "mmmm..." stuff some test input or is your keyboard broken?

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags to your question. The code is clearly no C code.

Comment: You appear to create a pointer for traversing the tree (trav) and then instead traverse the tree using your root node pointer (r) before resetting your r to trav at the end. It's not wrong, but it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

At beginning, 'r' is not assigned, that is, 'r' is NULL pointer.
So In 'Insert' function, no values can be insert to Tree.
I think it is likely that the first input value is to be set as a default value. And then 'r' must be initialized at this point.

```
class Tree                              //class for tree
{
public:
    TreeNode *r;

    Tree()
    {
        r = NULL;
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        release(r);
    }

    void release(TreeNode * node)
    {
        if (node != NULL)
        {
            release(node->left);
            release(node->right);

            delete node;
            node = NULL;
        }
    }

    void insert(int data)
    {
        if (r == NULL)
        {
            r= new TreeNode(data);
            return;
        }
     ...
```

And you need to add logic to releasing the all memories allocated to 'r' in the destructor of the 'Tree' class.

Comment: Can you tell me the logic to write the destructor to free the memory for this case.

Comment: It seems to be resolved by releasing memory, similar to your print() function. I fixed some of my answers. I hope to be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Change the *Tree* constructor to something like this:

```
Tree(int root_data) {
    r = new TreeNode(root_data);
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
}
```

And replace

```
Tree T;
```

with

```
int some_value;
Tree T(some_value);
```

Comment: This breaks the specification. Instead he should create the root node in `insert` if it does not exist.

Comment: What specification? OP did not state in the post or in any comment in the code that. I agree that's another viable option, I just don't see why mine is in any way going against OP's request.